# Js files not loading in heroku production with rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

my rails app working in localhost with all js files, but when i run in heroku production, that doesn't load any js files?

**config/application.rb**
    config.cache_classes = true

```
# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true

# Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
# config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

# Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

# Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure
cookies.
# config.force_ssl = true

# See everything in the log (default is :info)
# config.log_level = :debug

# Prepend all log lines with the following tags
# config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

# Use a different logger for distributed setups
# config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

# Use a different cache store in production
# config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
# config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are
already added)
# config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

# Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
# config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Enable threaded mode
# config.threadsafe!

# Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
# the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
config.i18n.fallbacks = true

config.assets.debug = false
# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

**config/enviornment.rb**

```
config.whiny_nils = true

# Show full error reports and disable caching
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

# Don't care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
config.active_support.deprecation = :log

# Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin


# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

**application.rb**

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery

//= require jquery_ujs

//= require jquery-ui

//= require twitter/bootstrap

//= require_tree .
```

**Gem file**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'rest-client' , :require => 'rest_client'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
#gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem "less-rails"
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
 # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

end
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

So when i run on heroku in my html head tag contains

```
<head>
<title>Admin70mmiq</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application- 
 7bf1caf8d9df45f41b2e2de526e0a07e.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/application-
561ebefa444229c0b9721488348e73eb.js">
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="zadsH75r/3ZNXRTijXuw7LJDNAflL/9J3DzDZJG9yi4=">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The asset pipeline compresses all js files into one file called application.js, which is visible in your HTML as `/assets/application-561ebefa444229c0b9721488348e73eb.js`

Comment: Here the issue, i have written script in my html.erb file, so after run the app, when i click on the button, that doesn't call any function

Comment: I mean i have written code like this in show.html.erb
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function () {

}
</script>

so when i click on the button this doesn't call

Comment: in firebug, that doesn't shows any error, but when i run on chrome, that shows some error, but that was worked on local. The error is 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileupload' of undefined application-561ebefa444229c0b9721488348e73eb.js:287
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload' home:40
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/58852.user.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: So thats the error. please frame you qs to be mode specific. Meanwhile have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185613/jquery-file-upload-error-uncaught-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-o

Answer (score 0):

hi budy please do following changes in file before deploy to heroku

------enviorment.rb-----

```
::ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true
```

------Production.rb------- if any new js or css create

```
config.assets.compile = ['*.js', '*.css']
config.active_support.deprecation = :silence
```

-------application.rb-------

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

i used this step when deploying heroku make sure you using "postgres" database and "thin" server hope you are solve the issue.
In GemFile two gem for Heroku : postgres , thin i not see this gem in  your GemFile.